# Corine landcover Geopackage for Germany only

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I've downloaded the CLC from  https://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/corine-land-cover/clc2018?tab=download as a geopackage because I could not find geopackages for just Germany.

Thus the datasize is quite big, i.e. too big for my project. I need the data for Germany only.

Is there a way to filter/delete all other regions but for Germany within the geopackage?

Comment: The BKG has a CLC dataset for Germany, maybe the specs are different, though. You can find it here: https://www.bkg.bund.de/SharedDocs/Produktinformationen/BKG/DE/P-2020/200408_CLC5.html

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that in the command line using ogr2ogr that is part of gdal library as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -progress -f GPKG -spat xmin ymin xmax ymax output.gpkg input.gpkg
```

where flag -spat is an intersecting bounding box in the coordinates of your reference system (spatial query extents, in the SRS of the source layer(s) (or the one specified with -spat_srs). Only features whose geometry
intersects the extents will be selected. The geometries will not be clipped unless -clipsrc is specified).